# can't serialize class org.springframework.data.geo.Point

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to put together an aggregation query for some GPS data using spring-data-mongodb 1.6.2. Here's what it looks like:

```
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(new Criteria()
                .andOperator(
                        Criteria.where("eventTime").gte(filterDate), 
                        Criteria.where("location").nearSphere(p).maxDistance(distance)
                )
            ),
            sort(Direction.DESC, "vanId", "eventTime"),
            group("vanId").first(Aggregation.ROOT).as("first")
    );

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,GpsDataEntity.MONGO_COLLECTION, GroupedEntity2.class);`
```

The problem I'm seeing has to due with the match() portion of the query. The exception is really long so I've included just the stack up to the point where mongoTemplate.aggregate() is called in the code snippet above:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class
>   org.springframework.data.geo.Point    at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:284)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:240)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:240)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:199)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:240)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:240)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:240)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putIterable(BasicBSONEncoder.java:309)
>     at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:248)
>     at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)   at
>   org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:131)    at
>   com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:33)    at
>   com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)     at
>   com.mongodb.OutMessage.writeQuery(OutMessage.java:211)    at
>   com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:86)  at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:81)   at
>   com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:317)   at
>   com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:296)   at
>   com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:371)   at
>   com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:243)   at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$1.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$1.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:324)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:324)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1418)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1353)

The above query works fine if I remove the nearSphere criteria. I've verified that the Point and distance being passed are valid.

If anyone can give any pointers on what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in Spring Data MongoDB.

Actually it turns out that "$nearSphere" is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression.
You must use geoNear(..) instead - see the example below.

Note that mongodb requires that geoNear is the first element in the aggreation pipeline.

```
@Test
public void serializePoinInCriteriaNearSphere() throws Exception {

    mongoTemplate.dropCollection(EventWithLocation.class);
    mongoTemplate.insert(new EventWithLocation(3, new Point(-73.99408, 40.75057), "42"));

    mongoTemplate.indexOps(EventWithLocation.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("location"));

    Point p = new Point(-73, 40);
    NearQuery geoNear = NearQuery.near(p, Metrics.KILOMETERS).maxDistance(150.0);

    TypedAggregation<EventWithLocation> agg = newAggregation(EventWithLocation.class, //
            geoNear(geoNear, "distance") //
            , match(where("eventTime").gte(1)) //
            , sort(Direction.DESC, "eventTime") //
            , group("vanId").first(Aggregation.ROOT).as("first") //
    );

    AggregationResults<DBObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, DBObject.class);
    List<DBObject> list = results.getMappedResults();

    DBObject firstResult = list.get(0);
    assertThat(firstResult.get("_id"), is(equalTo((Object)"42")));
}
```

you could also use `Critiera.within` with a `Circle`:

```
@Test
public void serializePoinInCriteriaNearSphere() throws Exception {

... as above ...

    Point p = new Point(-73, 40);
    Circle circle = new Circle(p, new Distance(150.0, Metrics.KILOMETERS));

    TypedAggregation<EventWithLocation> agg = newAggregation(EventWithLocation.class, //
            match(where("eventTime").gte(1).and("location").withinSphere(circle)) //
            , sort(Direction.DESC, "eventTime") //
            , group("vanId").first(Aggregation.ROOT).as("first") //
    );

... as above
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Thomas. So is there no way to replicate this query (which seems to work ok)?   db['gps-events'].aggregate(
[
 { $match : { eventTime : { $gt: new ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z") }, location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[-109,48],.012]}} } },
 { $sort: {vanId: 1, eventTime: -1}},
 { 
     $group : { _id: "$vanId", first: { $first: "$$ROOT" } }
 }
]);

Comment: I added an alternative variant - which should do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, thanks again Thomas. Keeping the near* and within* stuff straight has been a bit tricky but this helps. I tested it and it worked perfectly.